# Get string between two characters MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, select

How can I get the string before the last occurrence of a period and then the space before the string of the first occurrence? MYSQL

I can't explain it but here's a visual aid. Thank you very much.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MYSQLs function:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(str, delim, count);
```

Referance: https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring_index-function.php

Like :

```
SELECT (SUBSTRING_INDEX('Lennon, John W.','John',2),' ',-1);
```

It wiill give you output as `W.`

Comment: This only worked for the first example, but this gave me an idea. I'm gonna try something using this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Using Sambhaji's Answer I formulated this, which worked on all instances (example above)

```
SELECT 
    (CASE
        WHEN LENGTH(NAME) - LENGTH(REPLACE(NAME, '.', '')) = 1
            THEN CONCAT( SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(NAME,'.',1),' ',- 1),'. ')
        WHEN LENGTH(NAME) - LENGTH(REPLACE(NAME, '.', '')) = 2 
            THEN CONCAT( SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(NAME,'.',1),' ',- 1),'. ', SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(NAME,'.', 2),' ', -1), '.')
        ELSE NULL
    END) NAME
```

Answer (score -2):

You can Use **"Like"** condition in sql statment

Comment: How would you solve the OP's issue using LIKE? You should really show an example or it should be written as a comment and not an answer. Also, it rather seems like a job for regular expressions than a straight up string comparison.